# Simple String Comparision not working in bash script

Tags: android, bash

I have a simple bash script.

```
# Which display is HDMI ?
for i in `seq 0 $displayLoopCounter`
do
    name=$(adb shell cat /sys/devices/platform/omapdss/display$i/name)

    if [ "$name"=="hdmi" ] ; then
        echo "$name"
        hdmiDisplay="display$i"
    fi
done
```

OUTPUT of my scipt:

```
dvi

hdmi
```

I'm running the scripts using **bash myscript.sh**

display0 is dvi

display1 is hdmi

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this, are you *really* sure that the values of `name` are what you think?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. Even I'm not able to replicate this..

Comment: Actually I'm reading data from adroid system.. I think its failing there

Comment: Err, @Katrik, if you're unable to replicate this, it's not really a problem. Replicate in this sense means get the same results as you specified.

Comment: After editing my Question. Yeah now its the problem :)

Comment: Spaces are missing around ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with the fact that you don't have spaces around the `==` in your `if` line. That makes it a single-argument expression about which the `bash` manpage states:

> 1 argument: The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.

If you run the following script (with no spaces around the `==`):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Hello >myfile0
echo fileData >myfile1
counter=1
for i in `seq 0 $counter`
do
    name=$(cat myfile$i)
    if [ "$name"=="fileData" ]; then
        echo $name
    fi
done
rm myfile[01]
```

you'll see that the output has both lines, `Hello` and `fileData`. Putting the spaces in, you'll get only `fileData` because that same manpage states:

> 3 arguments: If the second argument is one of the binary conditional operators listed above under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS, the result of the expression is the result of the binary test using the first and third arguments as operands.

Comment: yeah may be.. Infact my script runs as expected for me too

Comment: but same thing, I'm reading data from android system files. It's failing there

Comment: Ohh.. If I echo "XX$nameYY". Its outputting YYXXdvi

Comment: before if statement its 
dvi\r\n
hdmi\r\n

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem: `[ "$name"=="hdmi" ]` -- the conditional expression does certain tests depending on the number of arguments it sees. When there's only a single argument, as you have here, `[` returns true if the string is non-empty -- here, no matter the value of $name, the expression `"$name"=="hdmi"` will always be non-empty.

You need

```
if [ "$name" == hdmi ]; then ...
```

Whitespace is very significant in shell languages.